# Deducing start and end of season information using r.seasons in GRASS GIS at 'Field' level

Tags: grass-gis, plugins, seasonal-analysis

I would like to ask one question on using `r.seasons` in GRASS GIS. The information page on this function is available at https://grass.osgeo.org/grass78/manuals/addons/r.seasons.html

The problem that I am facing is with regards to deducing seasonal information of Sugarcane Crop for a particular area between 2016 and 2020. I am using Sentinel-2 imagery and have already got the decadal maps (10-day maps). I am doing the analysis at the 'Field' level with demarcated boundaries, whereas the output of the r.seasons function is at the pixel level.

Using the zonal statistics function combined with majority mode, I am able to deduce the number of seasons in every field but when I am trying to fetch the start and end of the seasons, there is an overlap because of the different seasonal properties of different pixels. This overlap got ignored when the majority mode was applied but to carry out further analysis, I require the following information at field level to forecast the crop yield:

1. The number of seasons for every field.
2. The start and end decadal of every season in every field.

How can I solve this confusion?

Comment: Did you produce the decadal maps (10-day maps) with GRASS GIS as well?